# What OAuth Frameworks are supporting PKCE (RFC 7636)?

Tags: .net, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, pkce

I am evaluating use of the authorization code workflow.  RFC 7636 uncovered a problem with public clients and suggested a solution. [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc7636) was published only in September, 2015.

Which OAuth2 frameworks have implemented the recommendations of that RFC (namely the "Proof Key for Code Exchange")?   Specifically, which of the following have a version which implements the PKCE?

- Spring
- Microsoft .NET

Comment: The question isn't relevant for Spring OAuth2 because the attack is limited to mobile clients and there is no explicit support in Spring for implementing those clients anyway.

Comment: Actually that's not quite accurate. Spring doesn't have native client libraries, but the server should be able to handle requests from a mobile client. You can track the feature here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/655

Answer (score 0):

It is neither Spring nor .NET, but [Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/) supports [RFC 7636](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636). Because Authlete is a cloud solution, you can try PKCE immediately without preparing a server machine and a client application. For evaluation purposes, it may be enough. See "[Try PKCE](https://www.authlete.com/documents/article/pkce)" for details.

[image]

<sup>Disclaimer: Authlete is a product of my company.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thinktecture's IdentityServer supports Proof Key for Code Exchange. From Dominick Baier's [blog](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/02/02/pkce-support-in-identityserver-and-identitymodel/):

> IdentityServer3 as of v2.4 fully supports PKCE and the authorization
>   and token endpoint documentation has the new parameters. Also the
>   discovery endpoint now includes the code_challenge_methods_supported
>   entry.

Also, Google [supports PKCE](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/oauth/current/msg15392.html) on their authorization server.